# Programatically retrieve a list of the Controls that ship with .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf

What I am looking to do is create a list of all the WPF controls that ship with .NET 4.
Ideally, this list would need to be a collection of string objects of items like "Button", "ListBox" etc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Kris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will retrieve all subclasses of `FrameworkElement` in the `PresentationFramework` assembly

```
var query =
    from type in typeof(FrameworkElement).Assembly.GetTypes()
    where type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(FrameworkElement))
    select type.Name;

List<string> controls = query.ToList();
```

Note: there isn't a very clear definition of what is a "control" in WPF... there is a `Control` class, but not all UI elements inherit from it. Most "controls" inherit (directly or indirectly) from `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: I think you meant `GetTypes`, not `GetType`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want *all* of them, you could search through the relevant assemblies using reflection and find any concrete classes that inherit from the control base class.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = typeof(FrameworkElement)
    .Assembly
    .GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(FrameworkElement)))
    .Select(x => x.Name);
```